# Xpath help to find element

Tags: xml, xpath

From this XML:

```
<Accommodations>
   <AccommodationSegment AccommodationCode="627|26234" AccommodationId="15390132" AccommodationName="blah" Availability="available" BasicAdultCost="180.16" BoardCode="SC" BookableByFAB="true" BrandName="blah" ClassCode="2*" Currency="GBP" EndDate="20170918" ItineraryId="si1068" MaxChildAge="17" NormalisedName="BLAH" NumNights="7" ResortId="558" ResortName="blah" StartDate="20170911" Supplier="TT2" SyndicatorRanking="100" Type="Apartments">
  <AvailableBoardBasis>BB</AvailableBoardBasis>
  <AvailableBoardBasis>HB</AvailableBoardBasis>
  <AvailableBoardBasis>SC</AvailableBoardBasis>
  <Address Address1="blah" Address2="blah" Address3="Tenerife" CityOrTown="Puerto de la Cruz" Country="ES" PostCode="34324" />
  <TelephoneNumber>+34 922370565</TelephoneNumber>
  <Description>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</Description>
  <GeoPosition Latitude="28.4129" Longitude="-16.5437" />
  <DirectLink System="FABRIX">
     <DirectLinkURL><![CDATA[https://ww9.websitek.com/deep_linking/deep_linking.html?rooms=1&amp;journey=Hotels&amp;checkinDate=11092017&amp;duration=7&amp;suppliers=TT2&amp;accommodationId=15390132]]></DirectLinkURL>
  </DirectLink>
  <AccommodationUnits>
     <AccommodationUnit AUID="H2" Code="2SC" MaxExtraChildren="0" MaxExtraInfants="0" MaxOccupancy="1" MinOccupancy="1" Name="Studio - Self catering" QuantityAvailable="9">
        <RoomRate Amount="180.16" BoardBasis="SC" Currency="GBP" EndDate="20170918" RefundType="refundable" StartDate="20170911" />
     </AccommodationUnit>
     <AccommodationUnit AUID="H2" Code="2BB" MaxExtraChildren="0" MaxExtraInfants="0" MaxOccupancy="1" MinOccupancy="1" Name="Studio - Bed and Breakfast" QuantityAvailable="9">
        <RoomRate Amount="216.91" BoardBasis="BB" Currency="GBP" EndDate="20170918" RefundType="refundable" StartDate="20170911" />
     </AccommodationUnit>
     <AccommodationUnit AUID="H2" Code="2HB" MaxExtraChildren="0" MaxExtraInfants="0" MaxOccupancy="1" MinOccupancy="1" Name="Studio - Half board" QuantityAvailable="9">
        <RoomRate Amount="268.36" BoardBasis="HB" Currency="GBP" EndDate="20170918" RefundType="refundable" StartDate="20170911" />
     </AccommodationUnit>
  </AccommodationUnits>
  <Address Address1="blah" Address2="blah" Address3="Tenerife" CityOrTown="Puerto de la Cruz" Country="ES" PostCode="73737" />
  <TelephoneNumber>0034 922384811</TelephoneNumber>
  <Description>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</Description>
  <GeoPosition Latitude="28.4119" Longitude="-16.5473" />
  <DirectLink System="FABRIX">
     <DirectLinkURL><![CDATA[https://ww9.website.com/deep_linking/deep_linking.html?rooms=1&amp;journey=Hotels&amp;checkinDate=12092017&amp;duration=7&amp;suppliers=TT2&amp;accommodationId=16271549]]></DirectLinkURL>
  </DirectLink>
  <AccommodationUnits>
     <AccommodationUnit AUID="H4476" Code="4476BB" MaxExtraChildren="0" MaxExtraInfants="0" MaxOccupancy="1" MinOccupancy="1" Name="Double Room for Single Use - Bed and Breakfast" QuantityAvailable="9">
        <RoomRate Amount="250.04" BoardBasis="BB" Currency="GBP" EndDate="20170919" RefundType="non_refundable" StartDate="20170912" />
     </AccommodationUnit>
     <AccommodationUnit AUID="H4476" Code="4476HB" MaxExtraChildren="0" MaxExtraInfants="0" MaxOccupancy="1" MinOccupancy="1" Name="Double Room for Single Use - Half board" QuantityAvailable="9">
        <RoomRate Amount="276.97" BoardBasis="HB" Currency="GBP" EndDate="20170919" RefundType="non_refundable" StartDate="20170912" />
     </AccommodationUnit>
     <AccommodationUnit AUID="H4476" Code="4476FB" MaxExtraChildren="0" MaxExtraInfants="0" MaxOccupancy="1" MinOccupancy="1" Name="Double Room for Single Use - Full board" QuantityAvailable="9">
        <RoomRate Amount="303.88" BoardBasis="FB" Currency="GBP" EndDate="20170919" RefundType="non_refundable" StartDate="20170912" />
     </AccommodationUnit>
     <AccommodationUnit AUID="H4476" Code="4476AI" MaxExtraChildren="0" MaxExtraInfants="0" MaxOccupancy="1" MinOccupancy="1" Name="Double Room for Single Use - All inclusive" QuantityAvailable="9">
        <RoomRate Amount="317.34" BoardBasis="AI" Currency="GBP" EndDate="20170919" RefundType="non_refundable" StartDate="20170912" />
     </AccommodationUnit>
  </AccommodationUnits>
```

I need to find get the first `<AccommodationSegment>`which contains the `RefundType="non_refundable"`.  There is an inner element of `<RoomRate>.` which holds this attribute.

The following xpath:

```
(//*[local-name()="AccommodationSegment" and //*["RoomRate"][@RefundType="non_refundable"]])[1]
```

Selects both AccommodationSegments(hotel( containing both AccommodationUnits(rooms) with refundable AND non_refundable RoomRate attributes

Why is this so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were so close:

```
(//*[local-name()="AccommodationUnit"]//*["RoomRate"][@RefundType='refundable'])[1]//..
```

Modified test data (note I used the MaxOccupancy field as record IDs):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AccommodationUnits>
 <AccommodationUnit MaxOccupancy="1" MinOccupancy="1" MaxExtraChildren="0" MaxExtraInfants="0" QuantityAvailable="9" Name="Studio - Self catering" Code="2SC" AUID="H2">
   <RoomRate StartDate="20170909" EndDate="20170916" Amount="180.16" Currency="GBP" BoardBasis="SC" RefundType="refundable" />
 </AccommodationUnit>
 <AccommodationUnit MaxOccupancy="2" MinOccupancy="1" MaxExtraChildren="0" MaxExtraInfants="0" QuantityAvailable="9" Name="Studio - Bed and Breakfast" Code="2BB" AUID="H2">
   <RoomRate StartDate="20170909" EndDate="20170916" Amount="216.91" Currency="GBP" BoardBasis="BB" RefundType="refundable" />
 </AccommodationUnit>
 <AccommodationUnit MaxOccupancy="3" MinOccupancy="1" MaxExtraChildren="0" MaxExtraInfants="0" QuantityAvailable="9" Name="Studio - Self catering" Code="2SC" AUID="H2">
   <RoomRate StartDate="20170909" EndDate="20170916" Amount="180.16" Currency="GBP" BoardBasis="SC" RefundType="non-refundable" />
 </AccommodationUnit>
 <AccommodationUnit MaxOccupancy="4" MinOccupancy="1" MaxExtraChildren="0" MaxExtraInfants="0" QuantityAvailable="9" Name="Studio - Bed and Breakfast" Code="2BB" AUID="H2">
   <RoomRate StartDate="20170909" EndDate="20170916" Amount="216.91" Currency="GBP" BoardBasis="BB" RefundType="non-refundable" />
 </AccommodationUnit>
</AccommodationUnits>
```

Comment: I updated your xpath query for 'non_refundable' nodes to be returned and updated my initial question. Any idea why this would fail to return the refundable nodes and still return those of roomType 'refundable' as before?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.   I modified your test data and everything worked as expected, I'll post the modified test data in my answer

Comment: sorry, forgot to add theres another node further up the tree <AccommodationSegment> ...

Comment: Still works for me.   Note:  In my sample I have `non-refundable`, in yours it's `non_refundable`  (dash versus underscore)  It's probably something like that.

Comment: sorry @SteveWellens, I keep changing the goalposts but have now updated my question! hope this now makes sense - I have no idea why my Xpath query selects both room types of 'refundable' and 'non_refundable'

Answer (score 1):

you can use the path you want as part of the actual node query you need, so something like this:

```
(//*[local-name()="AccommodationUnit" and //*["RoomRate"][@RefundType="refundable"]])[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is a general approach, but it's a very simple solution:

```
//AccommodationUnit[//@RefundType = 'refundable'][1]
```

This selects the first `AccommodationUnit` node of your example.